# How to change the language of datetime?

Tags: xetex, languages, datetime

Сondition to change language of the month on titlepage doesn't work.

How to write condition to activate russian or english date depending on the choice?

XeLaTeX is used.

My code doesn't work. **MWE:**

```
\documentclass[10pt, oneside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setotherlanguage{russian}
\foreignlanguage{russian}

\usepackage{datetime}

\ifthenelse{\umruslang>0}
{ %rus
\newcommand{\rus}[1]{\foreignlanguage{russian}{#1}}
\newdateformat{docdatef}{\rus{\monthname\ \THEYEAR}}
}
{%eng
\newdateformat{docdatef}{\monthname\ \THEYEAR}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The language definition file `dt-russian.def` (provided by `datetime`) uses commands like `\cyrya` in the month names, which aren't provided with XeLaTeX. However, `datetime` has been replaced by [`datetime2`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2) and the corresponding [`datetime2-russian`](https://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2-russian) module (which needs to be installed separately) provides UTF-8 support.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{russian}

\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Liberation Serif}

\usepackage[en-GB,russian]{datetime2}

\DTMlangsetup[en-GB,russian]{showdayofmonth=false}

\begin{document}
\today

\selectlanguage{russian}

\today

\end{document}
```

[image: January 2018 января 2018 г.]

Answer (score 0):

I agree that `datetime2` is better, but you can also do it with `datetime`, provided you translate the calls of `\cyr?` and `\CYR?` into their Unicode counterparts, which can be done with the help of `t2aenc.dfu`.

```
\documentclass[10pt, oneside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainfont{Old Standard} % supports Cyrillic

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{russian}

\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{expl3}

\newcommand{\rus}[1]{\foreignlanguage{russian}{#1}}
\newdateformat{docdatef}{\rus{\monthname\ \THEYEAR}}

%% convert \cyr? and \CYR? to unicode
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \str_if_in:nn {xn} { T }
\group_begin:
\cs_set:Npn \DeclareUnicodeCharacter #1 #2
 {
  \tl_if_single:nT { #2 }
   {
    \str_if_in:xnT { \str_upper_case:f { \tl_to_str:n { #2 } } } { CYR }
     {
      \cs_gset:Npn #2 { \symbol{"#1} }
     }
   }
 }
\file_input:n { t2aenc.dfu }
\group_end:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\today

{\docdatef\today}

\end{document}
```

[image]